# Background image on a button

Tags: html, css

I am having trouble adding background image to my button, it doesnt display the entire image. How do I set up css properly for this?

I am trying to achieve this:
[image]

I want also this to be responsive, and possible to add box shadow as an active class.

```css
button {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/F88BjNN.png');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 40px;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

Comment: That is because you have set `background-size: cover`, so the image will be scaled up proportionately until the shortest axis is covered. With your current setup, there is no way of preserving the proportions of the background image while sizing it to a button of variable/unknown aspect ratio.

Comment: You need to provide similar ratio width and height to the button too in case if you want the image to fit perfectly inside the button.

Comment: Try using `background-size: contain` and `background-repeat: no-repeat`. Also use `border: none` to remove the border.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify the position property also you have to set the background size at 100%

```css
button {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/F88BjNN.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  height: 30px;
  padding: 40px;
  border:none;
  width: 250px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I have made some changes in your CSS. I think this is what you trying to achieve.

```css
button {
  background-image: url('https://i.imgur.com/F88BjNN.png');
  background-size: 100% 100%;
  background-position:left;
  display: flex;
  height: 20px;
  padding: 40px;
  border:none;
  width: 250px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.buttons {
  display: flex;
  gap: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div class="buttons">
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
  <button>test</button>
</div>
```